# Best Practice Method for Including Images in a DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

All, I have a WPF `DataGrid`. This `DataGrid` shows files ready for compilation and should also show the progress of my compiler as it compiles the files. The format of the `DataGrid` is

```
Image|File Path |State
-----|----------|-----   
*    |C:\AA\BB  |Compiled
&    |F:\PP\QQ  |Failed
>    |G:\HH\LL  |Processing
....
```

The problem is the image column (the *, &, and > are for representation only). I have a `ResourceDictionary` that contains hundreds of vector images as `Canvas` objects:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_acorn" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0">
    <Path Width="22.3248" Height="25.8518" Canvas.Left="13.6757" Canvas.Top="11.4012" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 16.6309,18.6563C 17.1309,8.15625 29.8809,14.1563 29.8809,14.1563C 30.8809,11.1563 34.1308,11.4063 34.1308,11.4063C 33.5,12 34.6309,13.1563 34.6309,13.1563C 32.1309,13.1562 31.1309,14.9062 31.1309,14.9062C 41.1309,23.9062 32.6309,27.9063 32.6309,27.9062C 24.6309,24.9063 21.1309,22.1562 16.6309,18.6563 Z M 16.6309,19.9063C 21.6309,24.1563 25.1309,26.1562 31.6309,28.6562C 31.6309,28.6562 26.3809,39.1562 18.3809,36.1563C 18.3809,36.1563 18,38 16.3809,36.9063C 15,36 16.3809,34.9063 16.3809,34.9063C 16.3809,34.9063 10.1309,30.9062 16.6309,19.9063 Z "/>
</Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, I want to be able to include these in my image column and change them at run-time. I was going to attempt to do this by setting up a property in my View Model that was of type `Image` and binding this to my View via:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" 
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Canvas}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Where in the View Model I have the appropriate property. Now, I was told this is not 'pure' MVVM. I don't fully accept this, but I want to know if there is a better way of doing this. Say, binding to an enum and using a converter to get the image?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What was their reasoning behind deciding it wasn't "pure"?

Comment: Some 'genius'/MVVM purest was having a go at me about a question I asked (and subsequently removed due to annoyance) on StackOverflow. Because I have never done this before, rather than argue I thought I would find out about the recommended approach first... Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd probably bind to a string representing the key and then write a converter to change the key to your image object. That way, `Image` isn't in your viewmodel.

Comment: Id probably bind to an enum or a string and then write a converter to convert it to the actual image. That way it's also easier to unit test that logic. (I'm not saying its impossible to test it if the image was in the view model, just that it's easier to compare with an enum/string than an actual image.)